# Modifying value of cell to include "string" before original value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba script that I have been working on(few hundred lines). One section of code is supposed to loop through a row of cells, and add a "string" preceding the rest of the data. I cannot figure out why this is not working, but I am suspecting I am overwriting my data somehow with the original value. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For y = 1 To 26
If UCase(Cells(1, y).Value) Like "*MISC COMMENTS*" Then
  Cells(1, y).Value = "Comments"
  For Q = 2 To lastRow
  If Cells(Q, y).Value <> "" Then
    Cells(Q, y).Value = "Misc Comment - " & Cells(Q, y).Value
  End If
  Next Q
End If
Next y
```

Data looks like

```
Misc Comments etc.  '<-- Header'

This is a simple    '<-- Data'
Problem but I       '<-- Data'
cannot figure       '<-- Data'
it out.             '<-- Data'
```

I believe my script should turn the data into

```
Comments                           '<-- Header'

Misc Comment - This is a simple    '<-- Data'
Misc Comment - Problem but I       '<-- Data'
Misc Comment - cannot figure       '<-- Data'
Misc Comment - it out.             '<-- Data'
```

Actual results with no errors (data is unchanged)

```
Misc Comments etc.  '<-- Header'

This is a simple    '<-- Data'
Problem but I       '<-- Data'
cannot figure       '<-- Data'
it out.             '<-- Data'
```

I believe my error is in the following chunk

```
If Cells(Q, y).Value <> "" Then
    Cells(Q, y).Value = "Misc Comment - " & Cells(Q, y).Value
End If
```

Although I just cannot figure out how I am calling it incorrectly.

Comment: Try     If isempty(Cells(Q, y))=False Then

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `Cells(Q, y).Value = "Misc Comment - " & Cells(Q, y).Value` and see if your code is even hitting that line?  If it's not, step through and debug to find out *why* it's not.

Comment: @DavidZemens I went ahead and added a breakpoint (new so this is an awesome feature to discover). It appears to be skipping lines with data entirely from my above `If Cells(Q, y).Value <> "" Then` statement. I thought this code would skip "blank" boxes and add data to boxes with data.

Comment: @bluerojo you are about to open up a new world of VBA: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx  Learn the basics of debugging, will save you a *LOT* of trouble!!!

Comment: @DavidZemens, your insight into `lastrow` helped me solve my issue. If you want to post it as an answer I can accept it since it was technically my issue with my code.

Comment: no worries, @jeeped put in plenty of work assisting on this one, and from the looks of it his code should also suffice. I'd say his answer is deserving :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Misc Comments etc.` is not the same as `MISC COMMENTS`. You need to wildcard the comparison string.

```
If UCase(Cells(1, y).Value) Like "*MISC COMMENTS*"
```

Here is a rewrite with a few more changes. It is unclear on what you wanted to do with the var containing *'last row of activesheet code'*.

```
Dim y As Long, q As Long, lastRow As Long, lastRowString As String
lastRowString = "last row of activesheet code"

With Worksheets("sheet2")
    For y = 1 To 26
        If UCase(.Cells(1, y).Value) Like "*MISC COMMENTS*" Then
            .Cells(1, y).Value = "Comments"
            lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).Row
            For q = 2 To lastRow
                If .Cells(q, y).Value <> "" Then
                    .Cells(q, y) = "Misc Comment - " & .Cells(q, y).Value
                End If
            Next q
            Exit For   '<~~ really want to exit the loop?
        End If
    Next y
End With
```

Comment: Sorry about that, my actual code has that in there. Still doesn't update the fields with my "Misc comment -" string

Comment: There was some confusion with `lastRow`. You assigned a string but used it as a long.

Comment: Is the `Exit For` statement interfering? Also, may be worth doing `If Trim(.Cells(q, y).Value) <> ""` because `" " <> ""`.

Comment: lastrow had the actual code to find lastrow. I threw in pseudocode for that part as excel decided to become unresponsive. And yes I did not mean to have the `exit for` in there. I will go ahead and try out your code.

Comment: If that doesn't do it, then use debugging to examine the value of `lastRow` -- it may not be what you think it is, for example if it's `1`, then your loop `For Q = 2 to lastRow` will never execute :)

Comment: @DavidZemens that turned out to be the issue with my code!. I create a new column (A) in a previous module and then this module runs `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` again and sets it to one. I just never noticed it until a couple hundreds lines down because I hadn't used my variable up until then.

Comment: @Jeeped yours worked as well because you set lastrow to `y` which is another great idea I need to implement.

Comment: @bluerojo - Yes, I added that while *lastRow* was still a string.

Comment: @Jeeped that was an error on my part for not writing that chunk of code out and I apologize for that one. I had it set previously to pull from a separate column. It was not actually "last row of activesheet code", I just put that as a sort of pseudocode